# Reading values from a DataTable column into a List<string> with LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a `DataTable` object with 5 columns returned to me by a service.  I am only interested in one of the columns, the `FuncName` column and would like my utility method that calls the service to strip out the extra information and just return a `List<string>` object with an element for the value of this column for each row of the `DataTable`.  This seems like a perfect application for link to read the values from the `DataTable` and then add them to my `List<string>` but I just can't seem to figure out how best to write that code.  I would think the `Any<>` method would be of some value, but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Out of curiosity, _why_ do you think `Any<>()` is relevant?

Comment: Likely just ignorance on my part.  I felt like because I wanted all rows in the list, that `Any<>()` filtered by an always true criteria would get me to the solution I was after.  I see now that `Select()` is a much better fit for my situation.

Comment: Correct.  `Any<>()` checks whether _any_ of the elements match a condition.  It returns a boolean.  The documentation is your friend.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
table.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("FuncName")).ToList()
```